# Follow href on frame change

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I want to give a Latex Beamer Presentation and it includes presenting some matlab code. I found out how to run a shell script with an href-link, but this includes clicking on something which is quite disturbing during a presentation. It would be great, if the script would be executed on frame change. Do you have any ideas what to do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Interesting question, but I'm afraid `beamer` can't do that. I hope somebody will tell I'm wrong.

Comment: You need acrotex or something similar to trigger the Javascript.

Comment: @percusse: would you be so kind and provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

The PDF specification defines a feature called [*Sub-Page Navigation*](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=388).

It intercepts PgDown/PgUp and arrow key pressing events to execute a pre-defined sequence of actions before passing to the next page. This feature is implemented in AdobeReader and requires the Full-Screen mode.

Example (executing a set of DOS scripts):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

%example scripts
\begin{filecontents*}{script-1.bat}
@echo off
echo hello world!
pause 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{script-2.bat}
@echo off
echo hello moon!
pause
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{script-3.bat}
@echo off
echo hello sun!
pause
\end{filecontents*}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Intro}
  \dots
\end{frame}

%define sequence of launch actions
\pdfpageattr{
  /PresSteps <<
    /NA <</S/Launch/F (script-1.bat)>>
    /Next <<
      /NA <</S/Launch/F (script-2.bat)>>
      /Next <<
        /NA <</S/Launch/F (script-3.bat)>>
      >>
    >>  
  >>
}
\begin{frame}{Frame with sub-page navigation}
  \dots
\end{frame}
\pdfpageattr{}%reset  

\begin{frame}{Conclusion}
  \dots
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}{Thank you}
  \dots for your attention.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. Unfortunately I use OS X, so I tried to adapt your code. I changed the `filecontents*` to:
    \begin{filecontents*}{script-1.command}
    #!/usr/bin/env sh
    echo "HALLO"
    \end{filecontents*}
and the `pdfpageattr` to
    /NA <</S/Launch/F (run:./script-1.command)>>
I also tried it without `run:`.
I use AdobeReader and it always says `Could not open the file 'script-2.command'`.
Do you have any ideas? (Sorry for the bad formatting, but I have no idea why the whitespace indentation is not working....)

Comment: Perhaps you should `chmod 755 *.command` before viewing the PDF.

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that. The problem seems to be using the right command in the `\pdfpageattr{}` part.....

Comment: I am able to open Textfiles with your code, but neither .tool, .sh nor .command files.